# Using rand() in switch statement

Tags: c++

I've been writing a randomizing program, but when I put a randomizing function, rand() into it the output is always the same. It's written in c++. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int genre, rVal, rCat;
cin>> genre;

switch(genre){
        case '1' :
            rVal = rand() % 7;
            rCat = rand() % 3;
            break;
        case '2' :
            rVal = rand() % 2;
            rCat = 1;
            break;
        case '3' :
            rVal = rand() % 4;
            rCat = 1;
            break;
        case '4' :
            rVal = rand() % 7;
            rCat = rand() % 3;
        if(rVal<=3 && rCat == 1)
            {
                rVal = 1;
                                };
            break;
        case '5' :
            rVal = 1;
            rCat = 1;
        break;};
        cout<< rVal << rCat;};
```

picking a 1 in genre will always no matter what make the result the same,
srand(time(NULL)) is called earlier in the program and every other randomizing function works except for the one in the switch statement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Did you call `srand()` in your code?

Comment: As @Yksisarvinen pointed out, rand() in C/C++ will never work without srand()

Comment: srand(time(NULL)) is in the code in the main function on the top, it even works with every other randomizing function except for the ones in the switch statement

Comment: Well, we will need [mcve] as pointed by NathanOliver. We cannot guess what is wrong with your code without looking at it.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `rand()`.   It's that `genre` is of type `int`, and all the switch cases are `char` literals  (e.g.  `'1'` rather than `1`).   So, if the user enters `1`, none of the cases will be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that genre is a char ? Your switch test '1' not 1..

Comment: oh wow, i thought you input ' ' into the switch cases no matter what, but this is the problem genre is not a char its an integer

Comment: Having a default case would have found this.